# How to call REST only after success of another

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, rest, axios

I have one rest request, it is called several times, and after all its successful responses, I need to call another, how can this be done?

I found these two rests, in the normal state they are called in turn in the exact sequence I need, but if there are a large number of requests, the process breaks

Comment: how many times you want to call the second API

Comment: Check out promises: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_promise.asp

Answer (score 1):

Please check the asynchronous pattern https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_async.asp .You can use await keyword to wait for a request completely, then check the response and decide whether to continue to call another API.

Comment: thanks!
Is it possible to send request only after appropriate response from another?
only if response of the network === 0 ?

Comment: what do you mean by the response of network === 0 ?